# Error en la ejecución de Convert

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un campo de entrada issue_date varchar(12) [este campo viene en este formato 06.10.2023] y debo cambiarlo a un campo tipo date en este formarto yyyy-mm-dd

Tengo esta sentencia:

```
select issue_date, convert (date, issue_date,23) as datec from tablapru;
```

Pero me marca el siguiente error:

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Issue_date, 23) as datec from ldz_deferred_mels
LIMIT 0, 200' at line 1
```

Comment: Hola sonlo. ¿Necesitas hacer el cambio para devolver los datos en un formato distinto (_visual_) o necesitas cambiar el formato de forma permanente (_almacenado_)? ¿El formato actual es `dd.mm.yyyy`?